# C++: кросплатформенный TCP клиент-сервер

Tags: c++, tcp-ip, клиент-сервер

Гуглил на тему tcp клиент-сервера, но выдает либо через WinAPI, либо через socket-ы Linux.
Неужели за столько лет не появилось нормального кроссплатформенного решения в виде приложения к стандартной библиотеке?
Прошу прояснить ситуацию

Comment: Да навалом их, начиная с буста/Qt/wxWidgets/etc, гугл в помощь.

Comment: Смотрю в сторону Qt, так как у него поразительная кроссплатформенность во всем, но с недавних пор ребята хотят денег и не понятно, какая последняя версия полностью бесплатна.

Comment: Qt бесплатен...... как минимум для некоммерческих проектов.

Comment: Неверно. Qt не позволяет разрабатывать для мобильных без платы + возможно в проекте в будущем я захочу денег. В том или ином виде.

Comment: @user64675, ну так бы сразу и писали, что под андроид пишете.....

Comment: @gecube увидел у них на сайте Qt open source версию. Это то, что мне нужно, я правильно понимаю? Я немного не в ладах с этой армией разных лицензий

Comment: @user64675, по-моему, да. На Qt писал в последний раз два года назад )))))

Comment: curl чем не годится?

Comment: Curl здесь при чем?

Comment: При том, что [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/), пожалуй, одна из самых популярных примочек к сокетам. Или без крестовых заморочек Вы не можете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, сети в стандарте С++, по-моему, до сих пор не появились.
Поэтому ищем дополнительные, сторонние библиотеки.
Используйте boost::asio или что-то подобное

Comment: boost:asio требует подключения всего boost? Я имею ввиду, насколько тяжелым это все в результате будет?

Comment: Ну, буст можно и помодульно подключать.  Это ж библиотека в первую очередь шаблонов. И это всяко лучше чем целый Qt подключать...

Comment: Да, но мне-ж еще и окна чем-то создавать надо будет. Я не знал просто, что Qt тоже может по-дефолту в tcp

Comment: asio можно и без boost. Цитата: **Asio comes in two variants: (non-Boost) Asio and Boost.Asio**. [Asio C++ Library](http://think-async.com/)

Comment: не будет это "тяжелым", что не используется, то и не вкомпилируется.

Answer (score 5):

Если сервер не высоконагруженный, то ничего искать не нужно. Все, что касается сети и под Win и под Linux будет будет с бОльшего вполне кроссплатформенно. Ну да, разные header файлы будут. Ну и под Win придется библиотеку подключить дополнительно. Но это меньшее из зол (имеется ввиду чем тянуть еще буст и т.п.).

Если же нужен сильный сервер, тогда, на мой взгляд, лучше вообще его писать под ту ось, на которой он и будет работать, а не придумывать себе сказку, что "сейчас я сделаю кроссплатформенный сервер, нужный всем и на всех осях и на все случаи жизни, и этот сервер будет держать 100500 соединений".

Что касается клиента, то здесь тем более нет проблем. Но это все относительно вопроса ( а там только про сеть упоминалось ).

Comment: Не спорю, но таким образом можно сказать, что надо писать вообще на асме ради полной совместимости. К сожалению я работаю 1 и подобное углубление в дебри для меня непозволительная роскошь

Comment: Не понятно Ваше упоминание здесь асма и какие дебри Вы вообще имели ввиду. Вам прояснили ситуацию, в которой Вы "плаваете". Если Вас не убеждает количество проголосовавших за этот ответ, то чего Вы вообще хотите от этого ресурса? Каких ответов Вы ожидали... только тех, которые устроили бы лично Вас? И таки да, я тоже фрилансер, но и на что это должно влиять по Вашему? Ваш комментарий говорит только об одном - о неумении Вами сформулировать свой вопрос. Как результат не верно сформулированного вопроса - не получили ожидаемого ответа. Но это Ваша проблема и вовсе не обязательно было ее оглашать.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри в сторону Qt. Они сейчас выросли в разы. Я бы делал на нем.

Так же можно использовать Node.js , он прекрасно работает и под вин и под линукс.

Php тоже самое, есть интепретатор под виндоус. Код менять не придется.

Comment: Сервер на Node.js хоть и будет писаться быстрее, но будет медленным. Что касается сервера-php - похоже на извращение)

Comment: Будет медленным??? Посмотри статьи на хабре node.js способен держать миллионны соединений. Я бы сказал лучше и дешевле варианта еще нет в принципе.

Comment: Я сам когда написал игру по Вконтакте сервер был на node.js пик нагрузки было по 30 тыс человек онлайн, задержек 0. Я бы выбрал node.js

Comment: Я понимаю, и понимаю, что не смотря на все старания, не напишу годный супер-оптимизированный сервер на плюсах.. но все-же, по опред. причинам node.js мне не кажется хорошей идеей. Да и тут смотря какое железо у вас у сервера было.

Comment: Какие причины? Даже на слабом железе все будет неплохо. Для игры я арендовал самый дешевый VPS сервер, который в онлайне держал 30 тыс человек. Даже си шарп, при 10 тыс в онлайн уже плохо себя чувствует (хотя может я с wpf контейнерами намудрил лишнего, было много модулей преобразования типов)

Comment: node.js может и держит миллионы соединений, т.к. все таки он на c++ написан, но как только обработчики (на javascript) запросов начинают что-то более менее тяжелое делать в плане вычислений, так пиши пропало (хотя это не такой уж частый сценарий, обычно пришел запрос - дернули бд - вернули ответ, здесь все ок).

Comment: Согласен. С вычислениями просто беда.

Answer (score 1):

Я щупал Qt и asio. Asio (в standalone-версии) - самый лёгкий вариант в плане размера бинарников и скорости исполнения, Qt почти не отстаёт по скорости, но библиотеки намного тяжелее (Qt5Core - 5+Мб, Qt5Network - 1.5Мб, тогда как бинарники клиента и сервера через asio были намного меньше 100 кб), но лучше документирован. Для asio почти вся документация идёт в варианте boost::asio, чтобы разобраться со standalone-версией пришлось денёк покопаться.

Если решение в основном планируется на STL, я бы использовал asio. Если же в проекте Qt уже используется, QTcpServer и QTcpSocket сильно проект не утяжелят.